# Cómo mostrar lista de usuarios logueados ? (PHP - mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

necesito ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo un pequeño sitio de gestión realizado en php + pdo + poo + mySql.

Tengo una tabla de usuarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ésto establezco la sesión, y valido el rol del usuario, si es diferente de 1 (admin) lo envío a su login.

```
 <?php 
session_start();

if($_SESSION['rol']!=1){
    header('location:../app/login/index.php');
}

?>
```

Con el usuario logueado puedo obtener fácilmente sus datos desde $_SESSION.

Podría al establecer la sesión, setear algún valor en algún campo de la tabla (por ejemplo "**activo**"), y establecer otro valor al cerrar la sesión?

Lo que deseo es poder tener una pequeña lista en el backend, de los usuarios loqueados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No he hecho algo parecido, pero se me ocurre que hubiese una columna, por ejemplo `activity`, y por cada movimiento que el usuario hace en el sitio se actualiza esa columna con `NOW()`. Si el usuario se desloguea se limpia el registro. Y para obtener los usuarios con actividad `SELECT ..., activity FROM ... ORDER BY activity DESC`.

Comment: El problema es que si el usuario no realiza logout y solamente cierra el navegador,  no se limpiará ese registro.
Por eso se me ocurrió hacerlo usando la sesión, mi única duda es como insertar el valor al momento de iniciar o de caducar o cerrar la sesión...

Comment: ¿Te puedes estar refiriendo a algo así? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426844/access-active-sessions-in-php